# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "int32"

Tags: type-casting

I am having following error with the latest solc (`0.8.10`) version, which was not happening in the `solc versiona 0.7.*`

```py
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "int32".
   --> contracts/contract.sol:248:26:
    |
248 |         int32 core = int32(core);
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Would it be possible to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [0.8.0 changelog](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/breaking/080-breaking-changes.html):

> There are new restrictions on explicit type conversions. The
> conversion is only allowed when there is at most one change in sign,
> width or type-category (int, address, bytesNN, etc.). To perform
> multiple changes, use multiple conversions.

`core` is of type `uint256`, to convert it to `int32` you are indeed :

- changing sign (from unsigned to signed)
- changing width (from 256 to 32)

Rewriting your conversion to fit the multiple conversions recommendation :

```
int32 core = int32(int256(core));
```

On a side note, `int32 core` shadows `uint256 core` which is almost always a bad practice.

Be careful about explicit type conversion behavior (truncating and sign interpretation), it is up to you to ensure that the values you provide are within range for a proper conversion.

Comment: Would I be in any danger, if I am sure that `core` contains a value that is at most 32 bytes? so there will be no risk of any truncation

Comment: Now, for `int256(another_core)` , variable was `uint32 `, I am having `Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint32" to "int256".` error. I had to do `int32(int256(uint256(another_core)))`

Comment: If you mean by at most 32 BITS , then you are safe for truncation but not for sign, any value >= 2^31 will turn on the 32th bit which will be interpreted as a negative number in int32. For `another_core` your conversion is fine, but if `another_core` is `uint32` as per your error message. why not convert it directly to `int32` ?

Comment: I was not able to do direct convertsion where int32(`uint32_variable`) gives the type conversion error again

Comment: It is valid syntax. `int32(uint32_variable)` works perfectly fine.